# Trying to get property 'nombres_cliente' of non-object - No consigo encontra el origen del error

Tags: php, html

me sale el siguiente error pero no consigo dar con el motivo del mismo.. espero alguno pueda darme alguna mano.. muchas gracias..

el error completo es

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property 'nombres_cliente' of non-object
>
> Filename: clientes/edit_vista.php
>
> Line Number: 31
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ventas_ci\application\views\admin\clientes\edit_vista.php
>   Line: 31 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ventas_ci\application\controllers\mantenimiento\clientes.php
>   Line: 76 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ventas_ci\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

este el el codigo html completo de la vista

```
    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>
            Clientes
            <small>Editar Cliente</small>
            </h1>
        </section>
        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <!-- Default box -->
            <div class="box box-solid">
                <div class="box-body">
                </div>
                <hr><!-- /.box-body -->
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">

                    <?php if($this->session->flashdata("error")):?>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                              <p><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i><?php echo $this->session->flashdata("error");?></p>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif;?>

                    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>mantenimiento/clientes/update" method="POST">
  **linea 31===>>>**        <input type="hidden" name="idCliente" value="<?php echo $cliente->id_cliente;?>">                    
                          <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nombres">Nombres: </label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombres" name="nombres" value="<?php echo $cliente->nombres_cliente;?>">
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="apellidos">Apellidos: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" value="<?php echo $cliente->apellidos_cliente;?>">
                          </div>

                           <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="telefono">Teléfono: </label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" value="<?php echo $clientes->telefono_cliente;?>">
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="direccion">Dirección: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" value="<?php echo $cliente->direccion_cliente;?>">
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="ruc">Ruc: </label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ruc" name="ruc" value="<?php echo $cliente->ruc_cliente;?>">
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="empresa">Empresa: </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empresa" name="empresa" value="<?php echo $cliente->empresa_cliente;?>">
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-succes btn-flat">Guardar</button>
                          </div>

                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
        </section>
        <!-- /.content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

Adjunto tb el codigo del controlador clientes

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Clientes extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("Clientes_models");
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = array(
                'clientes' => $this->Clientes_models->getClientes_models(),
            );
        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
        $this->load->view('layouts/aside');
        $this->load->view('admin/clientes/list_clientes',$data);
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer');

    }

    public function add_funcion()
    {
        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
        $this->load->view('layouts/aside');
        $this->load->view('admin/clientes/add_vista');
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
    }

    public function store_funcion()
    {
        $nombre = $this->input->post("nombre");
        $apellido = $this->input->post("apellido");
        $telefono = $this->input->post("telefono");
        $direccion = $this->input->post("direccion");
        $ruc = $this->input->post("ruc");
        $empresa = $this->input->post("empresa");
        if ($nombre=='') 
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "   El campo nombre no puede quedar en blanco");
            redirect(base_url()."mantenimiento/clientes/add_funcion");
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array(
            'nombres_cliente' => strtoupper($nombre),
            'apellidos_cliente' => strtoupper($apellido),
            'telefono_cliente' => strtoupper($telefono),
            'direccion_cliente' => strtoupper($direccion),
            'ruc_cliente' => $ruc,
            'empresa_cliente' => strtoupper($empresa),
            'estado_cliente' => "1"
            );
            if ($this->Clientes_models->save_model($data))
            {
                redirect(base_url()."mantenimiento/clientes");
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata("error","Hubo un problema al guardar la informacion");
                redirect(base_url()."mantenimiento/clientes/add_vista");
            }
        }

    }
        public function edit_funcion($id)
        {
            $data = array
                (
                    'cliente' => $this->Clientes_models->getClientes_models($id),
                );
            $this->load->view('layouts/header');
            $this->load->view('layouts/aside');
linea 76===>>>  $this->load->view('admin/clientes/edit_vista', $data);
            $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
        }

    public function update_funcion()
    {
        $idCliente = $this->input->post("idCliente");
        $nombre = $this->input->post("nombres");
        $apellido = $this->input->post("apellidos");
        $telefono = $this->input->post("telefono");
        $direccion = $this->input->post("direccion");
        $ruc = $this->input->post("ruc");
        $empresa = $this->input->post("empresa");
        if ($nombre=='') 
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "   El campo nombre no puede quedar en blanco");
            redirect(base_url()."mantenimiento/clientes/add_funcion");
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array(
            'nombres_cliente' => strtoupper($nombre),
            'apellidos_cliente' => strtoupper($apellido),
            'telefono_cliente' => strtoupper($telefono),
            'direccion_cliente' => strtoupper($direccion),
            'ruc_cliente' => $ruc,
            'empresa_cliente' => strtoupper($empresa),
            );
            if ($this->Clientes_models->update_model($idCliente, $data))
            {
                redirect(base_url()."mantenimiento/clientes");
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata("error","Hubo un problema al guardar la informacion");
                redirect(base_url()."mantenimiento/clientes/add_vista");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Estás tratanto a `$cliente` como si fuese un objeto, cuando parece ser un array. Las llamadas a métodos o propiedades de objetos se hacen con esta notación: `$objeto->propiedad`, en cambio, cuando es un array, se hacen así: `$objeto["clave"]`. Indícanos lo que te devuelve un `var_dump($cliente);` Es muy probable que tengas que cambiar el código, poniéndolo así: `$cliente["nombres_cliente"];`

Comment: hola @A.Cedano, muchas gracias x tu resp, como me dijiste al dar el var_dump() me devuelve un array completo, como dato te cuento q estaba tratando de la misma forma otro llamado a la BD y me funciono, lo único diferente es que tenia menos columnas la tabla. Me podrías indicar un ejemplo de como debería proceder??  y si te podría mostrar como fue el otro ejemplo q t mencione.. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: 'public function getClientes_models()
 {
  $this->db->where("estado_cliente","1");
  $resultados = $this->db->get("clientes");
  return $resultados->result();
 }'

este el el modelo getClientes, tengo entendido q el return deberia retornar solo un registro, de la tabla o estoy equivocado?

Comment: El por qué en un caso no te funcionó y en otro sí no depende de la cantidad de datos, sino de la forma en que organizas los datos dentro del método que llamas. Cuando se trabaja con resultados de bases de datos o con cualquier otro resultado, los datos se pueden devolver organizados como arrays, como objetos PHP, como JSON, etc. **Eso depende de cómo se haya escrito el  método**. Cuando quieras conocer la constitución de un objeto, usa `var_dump($objeto);` a modo de prueba, así podrás ver cómo está constituido y cómo leerlo... o modificar el método que lo produce para crearlo de otra forma.

Comment: En cuanto a tu otro comentario, no necesariamente debe devolver un registro. Parece que lo que se está pidiendo ahí es que devuelva los registros cuyo `estado_cliente` es igual a `1`. Si hay `n` registros que cumplen esa condición, vas a obtener esos `n` registros en los resultados. Eso es lo que interpreto viendo el código. Puede que me equivoque. Por cierto, si usas algún framework como Laravel, CodeIgniter, etc conviene que lo menciones también en tus preguntas.

Comment: Entiendo, yo tenia entendido que debería que funcionaba como un bucle y que a cada pasada por el return(); pasaba un registro, y volvía a preguntar y así.. muchísimas gracias x la aclaración.. me podrías guiar por donde debería empezar a proceder para arreglar mi código?? mucha gracias!!